# mysql php handling no data after select

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know how to handle no data or error code 1329 after executing a query.

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE device_id=?');
$stmt->bind_param("s", $device_id);
$flag = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($Username);
```

I'm expecting this code to come through however since it executes, the flag is true.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: `PDOStatement::rowCount()` only applies to `DELETE`, `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing it like this:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE device_id=?');
$stmt->bind_param("s", $device_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($Username);
if($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "Found $Username";
} else {
    echo "Did not find any user";
}
$stmt->close();
```